# Holding last value based on a condition in another columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.10

How can I hold the last value based on another column and repeat it until the condition is true
I tried but it shows me an error

```
conditions = [
(df['position'] ==-1) & (df['signl']==0),
(df['position'] ==0) & (df['signl']==0),
(df['position'] ==1) & (df['signl']==1),
(df['position'] ==0) & (df['signl']==1)
]
choices = [df['open'],df['open'].shift(),df['open'],df['open'].shift()]
df['test'] = np.select(conditions,choices,default=None)
```

I want the output be like this :

```
open        signl   position    test
42313.12        0   NaN         None
42257           0   0           42313.12
42128.03        1   1           42128.03
42072.26        1   0           42128.03
42149           1   0           42128.03
42154.99        1   0           42128.03
42166.63        0   -1          42166.63
42143.01        0   0           42166.63
42192.13        0   0           42166.63
42195.23        0   0           42166.63
42144.94        0   0           42166.63
42156.52        1   1           42156.52
42169.98        1   0           42156.52
42088.72        1   0           42156.52
42097.33        1   0           42156.52
41995.75        1   0           42156.52
41954.59        0   -1          41954.59
41949.95        0   0           41954.59
42005.71        0   0           41954.59
41987.55        0   0           41954.59
41909.43        0   0           41954.59
```

Comment: What are you using? Pandas? And which python version are you using? Please add corresponding tags

Comment: yes i am using pandas and Python 3.10.0

Comment: Please share the error message you're getting.